# Interpret multiple statement from operators of "?" and ":"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am still beginning to learn how pinescript works, and i am a bit confused / in need of some confirmation, reading part of these function codes

```
adr(length) =>
    range = high - low
    sma(range[1], length)
adr_high(adr_length) =>
    adr_ = adr(adr_length)
    high - low < adr_ ? low + adr_ : close >= open ? low + adr_ : high
adr_low(adr_length) =>
    adr_ = adr(adr_length)
    high - low < adr_ ? high - adr_ : close >= open ? low : high - adr_
```

how do you interpret the line `high - low < adr_ ? high - adr_ : close >= open ? low : high - adr_`?

is it true if i interpret it like this?
`if (high - low < adr_)` then return `(high - adr_)` if it FALSE, then check again `if (close >= open)` if it TRUE then return `low`, else return `high - adr_`

Comment: Yes you are interpreting that correctly.

Comment: @smashapalooza great! thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ternary operator should be used this way :

```
result = condition ? result1 : result2
```

you get the same result with :

```
if condition
    result := result1
else
    result := result2
```

of course instead result1, you can use another ternary indicator.

In your example you are interpreting it right.